# How to fix FATAL: database "school-grades-project" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am upgrading SQLite3 to PostgreSQL so that it can be deployed to Heroku.

Where else do I have to indicate that the database's name is our-school-project?

This is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


development:
  <<: *default
  database: school-grades-project
  host: localhost

test:
  <<: *default
  database: grades_test
  host: localhost

production:
  <<: *default
  database: grades_production
```

When I issue:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "school-grades-project" does not exist
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:50:in `rescue in postgresql_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:33:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:887:in `new_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:910:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:871:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:593:in `checkout'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:437:in `connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1119:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:221:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:189:in `connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "school-grades-project" does not exist
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `new'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:46:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:887:in `new_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:910:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:871:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:593:in `checkout'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:437:in `connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1119:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:221:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:189:in `connection'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `migrate'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `each'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `rails db:create` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Grammar is very important on SO; This site is like an online reference book, not a message board or forum. Please put in the effort as that reflects on the site and it encourages others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rails db:create`, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

1) Gemfile:

`gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'`

2) install pg on your development environment

3) database.yml example:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: corsego_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: corsego_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: corsego_production
  username: corsego
  password: <%= ENV['corsego_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

4)

`bundle`

`bundle update`

`rails db:create db:migrate`